# Line comprehension in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to write a small program that replaces certain values in an array with the desired value. The array (called "arr") contains about 10,000 elements of integer type and i would like to replace the digits 3,4 and 5 with 1.

I wrote the following code but it does not perform the desired function. Could someone help me figure out the logical error I am making. Thanks!

```
a=[1 if x==3|x==4|x==5 else x for x in arr]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical OR is `or`, not `|`. `|` is bitwise OR. This list comprehension should be written as

```
a = [1 if x == 3 or x == 4 or x == 5 else x for x in arr]
```

or

```
a = [1 if x in (3, 4, 5) else x for x in arr]
```

Libraries like NumPy use `|` for broadcasted logical OR because `or` can't be overloaded, but even then, you generally need to parenthesize your comparisons to override the high precedence of `|`. If you're using NumPy, then instead of a list comprehension, you should do

```
a = np.where((arr == 3) | (arr == 4) | (arr == 5), 1, arr)
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing now is called: `bitwise OR`. You should use a logical or: `or`.

Better yet, you can use `in` operator to test.

```
a = [1 if x in (3,4,5) else x for x in arr]
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! I will keep this in mind. Thanks

Comment: although small, should use the set `{3, 4, 5}` instead of the tuple

Comment: If `timeit` is to be trusted, I find tuple-contains 2.5x faster than set-contains. Mostly (I am guessing) because it is faster to iterate over 3 items and check instead of getting the hashes, followed by iteration and then a check.